# Is constant invariability needed in simulation of equations of motion

Tags: simulations

Let's take for example the equation of motion for a pendulum.

$$\ddot{\theta} = \frac{g}{L}sin(\theta)$$

Discretizing gets us

$$y_{i + 1} = \left(\frac{g}{L}sin(\theta)\right)h^2 - y_{i - 1} + 2y_i$$

If I have a simulation running which calculates new values for $y_{i + 1}$, can $L$ change and have the simulation still represent what would happen in real life if $L$ would change at that time point?

$L$ is not considered as $L(t)$ so it is not treated as time dependent when using the lagrangian method for getting the equations of motion.

## Problem Origin

I am deriving the equations of motion for a rocket in three dimensions but i have not considered the mass of the rocket as a function of time neither the inertia in each rotation axis. While the simulation is running the value of  can be changed by whoever is running the program. Is this ok or do i need to recalculate everything considering () instead? Same goes for the length  to the center of mass.

Comment: How can $L$ change and not be a function of $t$?

Comment: @ACuriousMind user input

Comment: Do you mean to ask if you can make things functions of $t$ in the equations of motion or if you need to go back to the original Lagrangian?

Comment: @jacob1729 Yeah sort of. Things like mass are considered to be constant but they may change throughout time. Though by user input, or more generally a function completely disconnected from the equation of motion.

Comment: What do you think it means 'to be considered constant'? Why do you think the fact they're changing by user input affect anything?

Comment: @jacob1729 ok so you're saying if anything will change at all it needs to be considered as a function of time.

Comment: But what physical situation are you modelling with that "user input"? Whether or not you need to consider new equations of motion depends on what system you are trying to simulate here! It's impossible to tell whether your simulation corresponds to "real life" if you don't tell us what real life situation you are simulating.

Comment: @ACuriousMind well ok so I am deriving the equations of motion for a rocket in three dimensions but i have not considered the mass of the rocket as a function of time neither the inertia in each rotation axis. While the simulation is running the value of $m$ can be changed by whoever is running the program. Is this ok or do i need to recalculate everything considering $m(t)$ instead? Same goes for the length $L$ to the center of mass.

Comment: Please edit that information into your question

Comment: @ACuriousMind done

Comment: If $L$ varies in time, then you need to start with that assumption. If it is an input but is held constant through the program, then you start with that assumption. I am not sure what is confusing you on that.

Comment: @KyleKanos Well yeah I think I've realised what mistake I've done.

Comment: The rocket example in particular seems worrying. Rockets work by changing their mass in a particular way, and if you allow a user to input discontinuous time series for $m(t)$ I'm not sure that's a good idea. The simple pendulum example with varying length $L$ is simple to deal with and you do just replace $L\mapsto L(t)$ like you suggest.

Comment: @jacob1729 The rocket thing was purely theoretical. But yeah alright, if anything will change in value at all discontinuous or not it needs to be $f(t)$. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @ACuriousMind wait just for clarification -- I ignore the equations of motion for $m$ and $L$ and i define the values for $m$, $\dot{m}$ and $\ddot{m}$ by the values inputted not given by the equation of motion for $m$ right?